# Mimic R's print(x, digits=n)

Tags: code-golf

In R print(x, digits=n) does something a little complicated.

It always shows all the digits to the left of the decimal point and then, if there are any digits to the right it rounds the whole number so that at most n digits are shown. However, leading 0s are not counted.  Here are examples to show how the function works.

```
print(2,digits=2)
2
print(23,digits=2)
23
print(23.12,digits=2)
23
print(2.12,digits=2)
2.1
print(0.126,digits=2)
0.13
print(23236.12,digits=6)
23236.1
print(123,digits=2)
123
print(0.00, digits=2)
0
print(23236.12,digits=1) 
23236
print(1.995,digits=3)
2
print(0.0336, digits=3)
0.0336
```

Given decimal number \$0 <= x <= 2^{40}\$ and \$n \leq 22\$ as inputs, your code should mimic R's print(x, digits=n) function.

## Rounding

This is different from my comment below, apologies. I didn't understand the problems with  rounding before.  It turns out rounding has no easily understandable rule in R (or Python for that matter). For example,

```
print(0.05, digits=1)
0.05
print(0.15, digits=1)
0.1
print(0.25, digits=1)
0.2
print(0.35, digits=1)
0.3
print(0.45, digits=1)
0.5
print(0.55, digits=1)
0.6
print(0.65, digits=1)
0.7
print(0.75, digits=1)
0.8
print(0.85, digits=1)
0.8
print(0.95, digits=1)
0.9
```

As a result, you can round either up or down as you choose in your answer. If you can follow what R does, all the better, but it is not a strict requirement.

Answer (score 5):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 44 bytes

```
f(x,n)=round(x,max(0,n-floor(log(x+0^x))-1))
```

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/7zaf5yw46f)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zgevubb4ja)

I think this should work??? Tell me if there's anything wrong.

Comment: @graffe glad to hear it! Always happy when ppl enjoy my desmos answers.

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 5 bytes

```
print
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGiNNulpSVpuhZLC4oy80og7Jtf0zSMdFIy0zNLim2NNLmMuIB8Y2QBY7CInqERhiCamJ4hUNAAKGiGJArkQwwwMjZDUm8GMgMsBJQ0RLHQEGy4gZ6BgY4CkjlYDDHUVICYAjJDz9LSFCZhDPEH0AxjYzO4KcYg14BEFBQUIJ5fsABCAwA)

Somebody had to do it.

Comment: Now you have to post a Python answer to make up for your sin :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 52 bytes

```python
lambda n,d:(f'{n:.{d}g}',s:=str(round(n)))[d<len(s)]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3TXISc5NSEhXydFKsNNLUq_Os9KpTatNr1XWKrWyLS4o0ivJL81I08jQ1NaNTbHJS8zSKNWMhem8xqhYUZeaVaKRpGOkoGGlqcsG5xuh8PUN0JRgiBkARM3R9RsZmYIVmSKKG6MYb6BkY4NJoiKxRz9LSVEfBGFWrsbEZqhjQfBNToFJLVDMhwiZYRU0NsIoagkUhobVgAYQGAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), <s>77 84 81 67</s> 66 bytes

-3 thanks to solid.py

```python
lambda n,d:len(str(n).split('.')[0])<d and f"{n:.{d}g}"or round(n)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3nXISc5NSEhXydFKsclLzNIpLijTyNPWKC3IySzTU9dQ1ow1iNW1SFBLzUhTSlKrzrPSqU2rTa5XyixSK8kvzUoCKoSaVFxRl5pVopGkYGesZGukoGGlqciGEjIzNwKKGSKIGegYGqOoM9SwtTXUUjFEUGRuboQoZGhmbmAJVWoI1Q6xfsABCAwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 34 bytes

```
\(n,d)round(n,max(d-log10(n)-1,0))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGagqLMvJL43MzczGTbpaUlaboWN5ViNPJ0UjSL8kvzUoCs3MQKjRTdnPx0QwONPE1dQx0DTU2oSn-wbg1DI2M9E1MzHSNNLiTjMIThAqbY1ZlCjV2wAEIDAA)

The answer is 29 bytes longer than the question...

Comment: A very nice answer too!

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 116 bytes

```
^\d+
$*
(1)+,([.0]*(?<-1>\.?\d)+((?<=\..*)|\d*))\.?([5-9])?.*
$2$#4$*#
^[.9]*#
0$&
T`#9d`_d`.[.9]*#
\.?(?<=\..*)0+$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYw5DsIwEEX7OQVSDPKSjLwQS5aAlFyALk4wkiloKBAldzeDAxQzT//N8rg@b/dLWfNjKnPMCpgEboRq@Yh6knzYdeYQcYhZKE5pHxGleMUshSDNx74LkxhQArOs2TLZwDximIiabeCUmpDTOSf8ys/N74tWDEqxrQUqVxuaGhZoggdP2jq/KFP3NGoN5u9X4FqDIfREGjnn3w) Link includes test cases. Takes input in the order `n,x`. Explanation:

```
^\d+
$*
```

Convert `n` to unary.

```
(1)+,([.0]*(?<-1>\.?\d)+((?<=\..*)|\d*))\.?([5-9])?.*
$2$#4$*#
```

Capture `n` in `$#1`, so that a balancing group can be used to count significant digits, but if we don't pass a decimal point, capture all the digits before the decimal point. Also note whether the next digit (if any) is at least `5`. Keep only the counted or integer digits and the next digit flag.

```
^[.9]*#
0$&
```

If the value is all `9`s and the next digit was at least `5` then prefix a `0` for the overflow.

```
T`#9d`_d`.[.9]*#
```

If the next digit was at least `5` then increment the captured digits.

```
\.?(?<=\..*)0+$
```

Remove any trailing zeros in the decimal part.